# Linux Centos - Mail Deamon Preferences

Tags: cpanel, whm

I keep getting emails from root into my inbox, I get about 30 a day which is annoying as hell and I'm wondering how I can filter these emails down so that I only receive the essential emails. I don't want to have an email every single time I log in via SSH, but when you 30-40 a day sometimes it can get pretty annoying. Is there a section in cPanel or WHM where I can tick or un-tick a section to choose which emails I wish to receive? I also get mail deamon bounce email messages which I'd also like to disable. I've looked and looked, but I think I'm either overlooking something simple or I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Probably better suited for http://serverfault.com/ but I'll answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In the WHM there are a few places where you can change your mail preferences.

*Main >> Server Contacts >> Change System Mail Preferences* where you can disable your forwarder for nobody, cpanel, and root mail entirely. Keeping these in place is recommended however, and if you are receiving junk such as cron job output then you should look to silence your cron jobs by redirecting their output to not be displayed (`2>&1 > /dev/null`).

*Main >> Server Contacts >> Contact Manager* where you can change what specific alerts you receive. If your **Minimum Alert Priority** for email is set to Low, then anything with a Low or higher priority (Low, Med, High) will get sent to you when triggered.

If you have other addons such as the CSF Security Software you'll need to tweak their email preferences individually.